# How to set onTabChanged on TabLayout in XML to call viewModel method?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-xml, android-tablayout

I'm working on an MVVM Android application. The fragment contains a TabLayout which looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tablayout_top_padding"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary_color"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary_color"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/icon_gray">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

I would like to be able to add this line in the xml:

```
 android:onTabChanged="@{(tabId) -> viewModel.selectedTabPosition(tabId)}"
```

The following error occurs:

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onTabChanged' with parameter type lambda on android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.

That is because the onTabChanged is a method for TabHosts and not for the TabLayout.

**Question**: 
I would like to know if there is a way to achieve something like the onTabChanged (example above) without the need of writing a custom BindingAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not answering exactly what you want to resolve, but here is a workaround: instead of using xml, you can bind a click event handler to the button programmatically on your Activity/Fragment class. For example:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FragmentRestingBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_resting, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

    binding.clickMeButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return binding.getRoot();
}

private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        viewModel.increase();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am really looking for a way to set it via the xml as shown in the example.